# Cloud + virtual private network vs. Local physical machine for company internal LARGE Git Repository: which option is better?

Tags: git, cloud

I am currently using a Git-Repository setup with Gitlab on a cloud server and accessing it with a public IP provided by the vendor.

However as the files stored in the Git repository get big, a lot of network disconnection issues occur causing the git pull/push operations to fail after waiting for a long time.

Currently I have two options:
(1) Buy a physical server and setup the Git server locally using an internal company router.
(2) Buy a VPN option from the vendor to make the network more stable on the cloud.

The problem I have is, I am pretty new to cloud services and have never used VPN provided by any cloud vendor. For option (2) I am not really sure whether using a VPN would really improve network stability or using a VPN does not really improve stability much because it still would go through the networking switches from my workplace to the vendor.

If anyone can give me some insights about whether option(2) works and/or how enterprises normally deal with their Git repository, I will be grateful.

Comment: Why do you think that VPN is going to make the network more stable?

Comment: I thought that because "conceptually" it makes sense to think that way and working with 192.168.x.x addresses would require less translation I guess. However I am indeed afraid of that's not the case and hence posted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. VPN is about "S", but *another S-es* - not Speed, but Security + Simplicity (for the cost of *some speed*)
2. Really you (your company) have **3 ways**, except already mentioned you can
   (3) Re-think your workflow and habits and don't store large binary artifacts in git-repos **OR** migrate to Git LFS with *local* LFS-storage

The choice between an external service and your own infrastructure is always a choice of a balance between three significant parameters:

- Cost
- Possibilities
- Responsibility

and this is mostly **not a technical issue, but a business issue** (BTW, offtopic on SF)

Comment: I am currently using a git-lfs enabled Repo however I did not know there is a functionality to store the large files locally. This seems to be the perfect choice for me and I will look into it.

Comment: I'm **not expert** in Git || Git-LFS and know nothing (or less) about LFS-storage under the hood, but according to (obvious) https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial `Endpoint` can be pointed to external (for repo-server) resource with something like `git config -f .lfsconfig lfs.url https://my_other_server.example.com/foo/bar/info/lfs` Note also note about access-protocols in https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial#lfs-url

Answer (score 2):

VPN isn't a dedicated link. It is a **virtual** network. It runs over your existing network and if your existing network is unstable then VPN will be even more unstable.